# how to chainload from image file which contain multiple partitions?

Tags: grub2

I have a disk images:

```
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  262MB  261MB  fat16        MemTest86             legacy_boot, msftdata
 2      263MB   524MB  261MB  fat16        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
```

In grub console I did:

```
loopback loop (some partition)/memtest.img
```

`ls` correctly show 2 partition `(loop,gpt2)` and `(loop,gpt1)`
`ls (loop,gpt2)/efi/boot/` show:

```
Benchmark  blacklist.cfg  BOOTIA32.efi  BOOTX64.efi  mt86.png  unifont.bin
```

However, if I do following, it gives error `not a valid root device`

```
root=(loop,gpt2)
chainloader (loop,gpt2)/efi/boot/BOOTX64.efi
```

What else I need to do to correctly chainload the bootloader?

update 1:
after loopback command the search command can find the partitions. For example the ls (loop,gpt2) shows a UUID E64D-A5AA. `search -u E64D-A5AA` show `loop,gpt2`

Comment: I wonder if the partitions would show up in a [search](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/search.html#search)

Comment: @PhilipCouling please see the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this operation is impossible unless the chainloaded efi and kernel support some way to mount the disk image.

The grub loopback boot process is like this:

1. grub mount the real hardware partition that contain the disk image
2. grub loopback the disk image
3. grub run efi application in that image. At this point grub give all control to the efi application. The efi have no knowledge about where to find the hardware partition contains disk image. Also it does not know how to mount the disk image even if it has this functionality. Thus nothing can continue from this phase.

In modern livecd, there are some kernel options allow you to tell it where to find the image and they can mount the image. But the grub have to directly run the kernel instead of the efi application which is supposed to launch the kernel. Because every path in the efi application is hardcoded and need to be absolute path.